# Making sure REST webservice has commited and client knows

Tags: sql-server, rest, web-services, transactions

I working on a REST webservice that offers a method to insert data into a database.

The problem is, how can I make sure the webservice only commits the data if the client knows about it?

The client might lose connection after sending the data, but the webservice commits it to the database anyway. The client can never know if this was successful and will try again next time, basically trying to insert the same data again.

So I was thinking about having a second method that does the actual commit, but this seems to leave me with the same problem? Although it might be less likely to occur as there is not much data being send.

Is there even a way to be 100% sure the client knows it has been inserted into the database, or do I have to make sure it cannot be inserted twice?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there even a way to be 100% sure the client knows it has been inserted into the database,

No.  Different network protocols can reduce the incidence of this.  But it's a fundamental behavior of distributed systems.  Even if the client connects directly to the database, a network failure after a commit is still possible.

So, yes you "have to make sure it cannot be inserted twice".  Typically this is done with a unique index so that a subsequent insert will fail.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a UUID which would be send again if the user tries to send the same data again. While this seems to be a good solution, this only seems to work while the user is actually retrying the same data right after it seems to have failed. What if he quits the app and tries again the next day, thinking the data didn't get through the last time? It would be a new UUID assigned to it and he still inserts the same data again. Even saving the UUID locally won't help as it could actually be new data, or he might actually want to insert it another time.

Comment: A unique index on a certain column or combination of columns is a good solution when we care about that column only (for example username). However, if we're talking about a table with 100 columns, where it's crucial to make sure to verify every column and check if it's duplicate data, a hash would come in handy. Every time you try to insert data, you can compute a hash of that data and compare it to any other hashes in the database, otherwise insert the hash with the data. That way you can compare reliably if the data is duplicate or not. Keep in mind, this is also not a universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to make sure the client knows is to send notifications to him. You might be sending all kinds of notifications depending on your use case - Emails, SMS, in app notifications, PWA notifications and etc. So, when you do the insert, whether is was successfull or not, you can inform the client via notifications about the result of the insert. Even in the case of the client being offline, the notifications will still be delivered when he comes online.

Comment: While this might help in certain situation, I don't think this always works. There are probably many things where a notification of any kind would be very weird, e.g. updating user settings in an app. Getting a notification for this would be very unusual and rather a workaround than an actual solution.

Comment: It really isn't a universal solution. It will probably be a solution to many bussiness cases, such as order creation, payment confirmation, data validity. Notifications come in handy in async scenarios, where a response cannot be returned immediately. In your case, updating a user profile, would be a synchronous operation, which would not get a response only in the case of user disconnecting after the request has been sent. The server would update the data, however the user wouldn't receive a response. Sending a notification for this maybe isn't nice, but it's better than silently failing.